# Is there an AWS Auth v4 implementation usable with a Twisted-friendly HTTP client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, twisted, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

I'm looking to do some Route53 interaction within a Twisted-based program.  I'm extending txAWS to support Route53 and looking at how to authenticate the requests.  txAWS some some rudimentary signature code but it looks like it will take a lot of work to make it usable for a new set of APIs.

boto3 includes an implementation of the various authentication systems - but ties it closely to the http library it uses internally (requests).  I could probably construct some kind of adapter between the two interfaces to be able to use this code, but ...

Has anyone else implemented (and open sourced) AWS Auth v2 in a way that makes it *easily* reusable by a Twisted-based HTTP client?

Comment: Signature Version 4 is fully documented and not that difficult to implement yourself. I've done it (though not in Python). It also has a [test suite](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html) to verify that your code is correct.  It is necessarily tied somewhat to the http library because it adds headers and needs to know/learn/be told what the existing headers are or what they will be.

Comment: Even easy code is work to implement and work to maintain over time.  If I _can_ use someone else's implementation, I'd much rather.  Turns out someone probably has one for txAWS (I asked on a mailing list) and they're looking into contributing it upstream.